# java HTTP server - supporting favicon.ico

Tags: java, favicon

I'm writing a java HTTP server and required to be able to return the favicon.ico.
the problem is I don't know how to read and write it to the socket output stream since it is not supported by ImageIO.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you create a static `favicon.ico` file and just serve that? It's going to be cached by your site visitor(s) anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ImageIO for this. Just transfer the bytes, same as for any other static resource. That applies to all static resources. You don't need to make this a special case in any way.